# Append strings to list from string

Tags: python-3.x, string

I'm working with a string that looks something like this (I save it from an error)

```
"['This is one' 'How is two' 'Why is three'\n 'When is four'] not in index"
```

From this string I would like to extract the substrings like this

```
['This is one', 'How is two', 'Why is three', 'When is four']
```

What I have done so far is to get the substrings (if the string is named `s`);

```
start = s.index("[") + len("[")
end = s.index("]")
s = s[start:end].replace("\\n", "")
```

Which gives me the output

```
'This is one' 'How is two' 'Why is three' 'When is four'
```

Now I just need to insert them into a list, this is where I'm having problems. I've tried this

```
s = s.split("'")
```

But it gave me the output

```
['', 'This is one', ' ', 'How is two', ' ', 'Why is three', ' ', 'When is four', '']
```

I also tried

```
s = s.split("'")
s = ' '.join(s).split()
```

Which gave me the output

```
['This', 'is', 'one', 'How', 'is', 'two', 'Why', 'is', 'three', 'When', 'is', 'four']
```

And I've tried the same but `.split("  ")` which gave me some weird whitespaces. I've also tried to use `list(filter(...))`, but it doesn't remove the strings in the list that has whitespace in it, only the completely empty strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach would be to first extract the term in square brackets, then use `re.findall` to find all single quoted terms.

```
inp = "['This is one' 'How is two' 'Why is three'\n 'When is four'] not in index"
srch = re.search(r'\[(.*)\]', inp, flags=re.DOTALL)

if srch:
    matches = re.findall(r'\'(.*?)\'', srch.group(1))
    print(matches)
```

Output:

```
['This is one', 'How is two', 'Why is three', 'When is four']
```

Note carefully in the call to `re.search` that we use `re.DOTALL` mode.  This is required because the content in square brackets actually has a newline in it.

Comment: You can simplify `r'\'(.*?)\''` to `r"'(.*?)'"`

Comment: Thanks for the comment, it worked to simplify like you said.